# What are the benefits of docker config over setting environment variables for containers?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

Both Docker config and setting environment variables for containers seems to accomplish the same goals.
Especially when considering the environment variables to set can get fetched from a file (env_file).

What are the benefits of docker config over setting environment variables for containers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many, **but it's mainly a matter of choice**. Here are some benefits:

- Docker config are immutable, where environment variable are not (this one may be both a benefit and drawback though)
- Docker config are easily manageable with `docker config` commands where environment variables are not
- Environment variables may collide in your container: you may use environment variable `MONGODB_HOST=mongodb://foo:bar@my-mongo:27017` pointing to Mongo database but a library you are using in your application will also use this variable **but** expect a simple hostname such as `my-mongo` and throw an exception at runtime
- Config file may have restricted read permission (i.e. only the applicative user may read it), where environment variable may leak to a sub-process or anyone accessing your container
- Config file may be splitted in several parts for readability or management in your container, environment variables cannot
- When checking what are your effective container configuration (i.e. running a shell in your container and looking around), using config file is much easier than showing a bunch of potentially unrelated environment variables (`cat myconfig` VS. `env`)
- In summary, config file are more partitioned and manageable than environment variables

You may take a look at [this post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/283715/what-is-the-preferred-way-to-store-application-configurations) which is not Docker specific but may give some insights.